A boy who sees bloody faces?
Many years ago I watched a movie about a little boy (5-12 years old) who was often seeing bloody faces. No one believed him (his mum was the other character I remember) and thought it was all imaginary.
Once, he was sitting in the car next to his mum and while they were waiting at the traffic lights, the boy saw a woman whose face was all blood but his mum didn't.
He visited a psychologist. Somehow one day, the psychologist eavesdropped a conversation between the boy and some psychopath or maybe, a so-called imaginary friend. That's when the psychologist understood that the boy wasn't lying and it wasn't all in his head.

Well, I'd ask for year and country, but this is clearly The Sixth Sense and everyone is about to say that anyway, so... ;)

Can you elaborate when you actually saw it? How many years are "many"?

The movie you are looking for is The Sixth Sense (1999).  
It's about a young boy Cole, played by Haley Joel Osment who was 11 at the time. He can see the ghosts of people, but he doesn't want to tell anyone. You have some of the scenes backwards; he is visited by the therapist, played by Bruce Willis, earlier in the movie, and the movie is largely about the relationship between him and his therapist.
The other scene you describe is towards the very end of the movie. He is in the car with his mom, and he says that he is finally ready to tell her his secret; that he sees dead people, including a woman who had just been killed in a car accident that's standing next to their car. 
